# cannot convert value of '()' to expected argument type 'String' swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I can't find anything online or on stackoverflow. 
I'm getting this error `Cannot convert value of '()' to expected argument type 'String'` when I use the let color. I'm presuming I need to convert () to a String.

```
func Change() {
    print("CALL")
    let colors = [
        no0 = "7A9474",
        no1 = "8C4482",
    ]
    let random = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(colors.count)))
    let color = colors[random]
    if random == current {
        print("FUNNY")
        Change()
    }

    current = random
    Change2(hex: color, number: String(random)) //HERE IS THE ERROR
}
```

Comment: Your `let colors = [ no0 = ...` code is not valid Swift syntax. Is this actually your code?

Comment: I've got the variables defined outside of the code posted.

Comment: Swift isn't like other languages where an assignment expression `(no0 = ...)` actually evaluates to the assigned value. It's just a Void expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let colors = [
    no0 = "7A9474",
    no1 = "8C4482",
]
```

I would assume `no0` and `no1` are String variables elsewhere.

Unfortunately in Swift, the [assignment is not a *statement*, but an *expression* that returns `Void` (i.e. `()`)](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-ID62). Thus the compiler won't complain about this declaration, even it certainly looks wrong to the human eye.

The expression `no0 = "7A9474"` can be viewed as a function that returns `()`. So the compiler will see an array of two `()` and infer the type of `colors` to be `[()]`.

```
let color = colors[random]
```

And thus the type of `color` is `()`. (Swift 3 will issue a warning on this line)

```
Change2(hex: color, number: String(random))
//           ^^^^^
```

And thus a type error on this line.

---

Perhaps you want this instead:

```
no0 = "7A9474"
no1 = "8C4482"
let colors = [no0, no1]
```

Comment: Is there anyway to get around this?

Comment: @MaxKrissigo It's unclear what you are trying to do. What do you want the array to contain? What are `no0` and `no1`?

Comment: Thank you, although I can't accept the answer just yet.

Comment: @kennytm +1 Great answer. I found your explanation "which the type is ()" to be somewhat confusing. Consider explaining that every function in Swift returns a value, even `Void` functions, for which the return value is the empty tuple `()`.  When one realizes that the assignment operator `=` is just another function that returns `Void`, it makes sense that the elements of the `colors` array were empty tuples.

Comment: @par Thanks. I've rephrased a little. What I mean is that `=` is not a statement (unlike say Python), so even if the `let colors` line is wrong the compiler won't complain about it.

Answer (score 0):

no0,no1...those index is already in array.

```
var current = 0
func Change() {
    print("CALL")
    let colors = ["7A9474","8C4482"]

    let random = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(colors.count)))
    let color = colors[random]
    if random == current {
        print("FUNNY")
        Change()
    }

    current = random
    Change2(hex: color, number: String(random))
}

func Change2(hex:String , number:String)  {
    //do ...
}
```